# Replacing garage door lock barrel

Tags: doors, garage, lock

Since I moved into my house, I've not had the key for my garage, so I'm looking into how I can get a new one. I've found what I think I need to replace on eBay, but there are a lot of variations on the same thing, and I don't know what the numbers mean or what I need for mine:

- [40/10](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Garage-Door-Lock-Half-Euro-Cylinder-40-10-50mm-Length-Overall-/110737689904?pt=UK_Home_Garden_Doors_LE&hash=item19c87b0d30)
- [45mm](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Garage-Door-Lock-Cylinder-Barrel-45mm-Zone-6-Pin-Security-Special-Offer-Price-/231190460519?pt=UK_HaG_Lock_Safes_GL&hash=item35d4067867)
- [40/40](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Euro-Profile-Thumb-Turn-Door-Lock-Cylinder-Replacement-Barrel-Eurospec-40-40-/320792357526?pt=UK_HaG_Lock_Safes_GL&var=&hash=item4ab0b6ea96)

Not entirely sure what these are (assuming measurement of one of the dims) but I don't know what I need, ideally I'd like to order the new one I need before I have to take the old one out, but I get the feeling I'm going to have to in order to measure it, can anyone give advice?

[image]

Comment: What about disabling that lock and installing a garage door opener?

Comment: There's no reason I can't, I just thought that'd probably be quite a bit more expensive, to be honest I'd not really considered it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lock barrel is known as a Euro cylinder (there's a photo [on this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder_lock) showing Euro cylinder locks booth side and end on).

The numbers XX/YY relate to dimensions (in millimetres) of the lock when viewed from the side. The dimensions are measured from one face of the lock to the fixing hole in the centre, then from the hole to the other face.

You can remove the lock, measure it, and replace it while you wait for the new one to arrive - it only takes a matter of seconds with the key to remove the cylinder. However, the bad news for you, since you say that you've not got a key, is that you generally need a key to be able to easily take the cylinder out. As you can see in the top of the photo on the link, the cam is slightly offset when the key is withdrawn, so it doesn't just slide out once you've removed the fixing bolt.

Comment: Ah excellent, this answer is pretty much exactly what I was after, is it worth removing the mechanism on the back of the door entirely? would that make it easier to remove the barrel?

Comment: For what it's worth, a locksmith would usually either pick this to the open position or open it destructively, then swap in a new euro cylinder (which will come with a new key).

Comment: Well that was my backup plan, I just thought that considering the barrels on eBay are about £5, and it might be a fairly simple project to do, I wanted to have a go at doing it myself. I figured a locksmith would be kind of expensive (at least compared to just the £5 barrel)

Comment: Wow, that is not something I'd like to do again, I've managed to take the whole mechanism off the back of the door, and with no small amount of swearing, got the barrel out, turns out its 30/10 :)

Comment: Good news that you got it apart. Was it straightforward enough to put it back together afterwards?

Comment: Yea, another large amount of swearing, but It's together again. This weekend when the barrel arrives, I get to enjoy it all over again

Comment: You'll do it in half the time this time! :-D

Answer (score 0):

I took the whole mechanism off to make it easy to work on the bench , took it apart to take out the lock with the broken key and fitted the new one i bought from Ebay ,GDS had the lock delivered in 48 hours with 2 keys £6 .00 i think . 10 minutes job done ..